# SQL Server Multiple JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

In MS SQL Server, I have a table that contains many parametric columns.
I have a separate single parameter table that contains all parameter values.
If I want to select parameter values for each column, I have to make a JOIN for each column.

In example below, I need to perform 3 JOINs **which I do not prefer since I may need many columns more**.
How can I JOIN with parameter table effectively?

[image]
Students;

```
StudentiD   RegistrationStatus   MaritalStatus   Gender   RegistrationDesc   MaritalSTatusDesc   GenderDesc   
1           RG                   SNG             M        TO BE JOINED       TO BE JOINED        TO BE JOINED
2           NR                   MRD             F        TO BE JOINED       TO BE JOINED        TO BE JOINED
```

Parameters;

```
GROUP                KEY   VALUE
RegistrationStatus   RG    Registered
RegistrationStatus   NR    Not Registered
MaritalStatus        SNG   Single
MaritalStatus        MRD   Married
Gender               M     Male
Gender               F     Female
```

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that images are frowned upon. Please post your sample data in text form or better yet, create a fiddle.

Comment: Text form cannot format data well to be clearly understood. How can I put excel table here without breaking the visual format?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: I've just submitted an edit with a simple way of making tables by just lining the data up with spaces.

Comment: @AhmetAltun could you check the answers you have received and confirm if they solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could always make this a function that you call within your select query, it's not going to be terribly efficient once you get to large data sets (read up on scalar functions) but it will make your code much easier to read.

Function;

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Parameters](@Group varchar(255), @Key nvarchar(255))
RETURNS nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
   declare @value nvarchar(255)
   select @value = [value] from Parameters where [Group] = @Group AND [Key] = @Key
   RETURN ( @value )
END
```

Your select query would call it like this;

```
SELECT
StudentiD
,RegistrationStatus
,MaritalStatus
,Gender
,dbo.FN_Parameters('RegistrationStatus',RegistrationStatus) RegistrationDesc
,dbo.FN_Parameters('MaritalStatus',MaritalStatus) MaritalStatusDesc
,dbo.FN_Parameters('Gender',Gender) GenderDesc
FROM Students
```

I would, however, not use the names 'Group', 'Key' etc as these are reserved words in SQL server, it's really bad practice and then requires wrapping in square brackets, take a read here;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Edit: I've modified the function to allow you to pass in both group and key just in case you have duplicate keys in there.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
'SELECT *'

SELECT @sql = @sql + CAST((
SELECT DISTINCT ',(SELECT [VALUE] FROM Parameters WHERE [KEY] = '+ [GROUP] +' AND [GROUP] = ''' +[GROUP]+''') AS ' +[GROUP]+'Desc'
FROM Parameters
FOR XML PATH('')
) as nvarchar(max))


SET @sql = @sql +'
FROM Students s'

PRINT @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
StudentId   RegistrationStatus  MaritalStatus   Gender  GenderDesc  MaritalStatusDesc   RegistrationStatusDesc
1           RG                  SNG             M       Male        Single              Registered
2           NR                  MRD             F       Femail      Married             Not Registered
```